# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] with angular selectpicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just was trying to set up [Angular selectpicker](https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select) and I've stumbled upon this error in my console

```
Failed to instantiate module selectDemoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:35:320
    at s (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:34:399)
    at http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:35:63
    at s (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:7:302)
    at g (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:34:399)
    at ab (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:38:135)
    at d (http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js:17:381
```

Here's my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/LpQmXB).

What am I missing? Because I can't see what's the problem. Seems like I included all needed files for this to work.

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app="selectDemoApp">

<body>
  <section ng-controller="SimpleUsageCtrl">

    <select class="selectpicker">
      <option>Mustard</option> 
      <option>Ketchup</option> 
      <option>Relish</option>
    </select>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var selectDemoApp = angular.module('selectDemoApp', ['angular-bootstrap-select']);

  selectDemoApp.controller('SimpleUsageCtrl', function ($scope) {

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Free tip** Don't use minified Angular javascript file in development. Error message are smaller and have less informations.

The `[$injector:modulerr]` appears when Angular can't find a dependency of the module. You have only one dependency, so we can guess that Angular can't find `angular-bootstrap-select`. Or maybe `angular-bootstrap-select` dependencies are missing.

Double check the javascript files in your HTML. You are missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added `angular-bootstrap-select` files in you html.

Install it using bower with following command:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap-select
```

then add in HTML

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap-select/build/angular-bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

You can download file manually and set `src` of script appropriately.